# IOS continues to block HTTP requests even though ATS has been disabled

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, extjs

this is so confusing, I have legacy app cordova that need to do some request to http url , I know IOS ATS to block that request, and I have done everything I read from the internet
enable like code below

```
    <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

and this is from xcode
[image]

is there any thing that i missed?

PS: yes it works if i put the url into NSExceptionDomains but the requirement is i need to open this to any http url because some client still have http url not https

Comment: The allow arbitrary loads keys should be directly under app transport security, not inside the exception domains entry.

Comment: allow arbitrary is not inside exception Domains its outside of it @GeoffHackworth

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. Not sure why it isn’t working then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the problem, its already state in apple documentation [image]